# how to print curly braces from database inside blade template

Tags: php, laravel

I input this code into tinycme using it's code snippet plugin:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

It produces code like this:

```
<pre>
    <code class="language-php">
        &lt;meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"&gt;
    </code>
</pre>
```

That exact code is saved to database.

In blade template I then print it out using:

```
{{ htmlentities($post->body) }}
```

All I get is this:

```
<pre> 
     <code class="language-php">
         &lt;meta name="csrf-token" content=""&gt;
     </code>
</pre> 
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Where did the curly braces go?

Comment: Why use htmlentities() inside the curly braces? Please try and remove these, since Laravel automatically filters html due to injection problems. When using {!! something !!} the output is not filtered.

Comment: it's the only way to get encoded html values like &lt;meta name="csrf-token" content=""&gt; instead of <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> which doesn't work because texteditor expects encoded html and not normal html when it initializes

Comment: No, Laravel does this automatically when calling something in {{ and }}, so inserting htmlentities will double the effect.

Comment: To print with escaped values use **{!! csrf_token() !!}** it will print the values exactly but take precautions.

Comment: thanks for your responses guys. I have figured it out why Laravel-5.3 would not print {{ }} that were saved in the database. It actually prints them but since Laravel 5.3 includes Vue, Vue eats them up. So When I disabled Vue I was now able to render curly brackets.